# Itext 7 IPdfTextLocation.GetPageNumber turning up 0 all the time

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext7

I'm writing a (VB/Net) procedure that searches a PDF document for a Regex pattern and writes a text file with the matched locations:

```
    Public Sub ReadAndMatch(ByVal InputFileName As String, OutputFileName As String, RegexPattern As String)
        Dim pdfIn As New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(InputFileName) ' A Pdfreader object associated with the input file name
        Dim pdfDoc As New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfIn) 'This object holds the actual document being analyzed
        Dim strategy As New iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(RegexPattern) 'extraction strategy
        Dim Parser As iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor = New Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy)
        Dim Loclist As System.Collections.ICollection 'all the matches
        Dim Location As iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.IPdfTextLocation 'one match
        Dim CoordFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter(OutputFileName) 'initiate output stream
        Dim TextString As String
        Dim L, B, W, H As Single ' Left, bottom, width & height of the rectangle containing the extracted text
        Dim pg As Integer = 0 'number of current page, number of matches in page, total number of matches
        Do While pg < pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages 'loop thru document pages 
            pg += 1
            Parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetPage(pg)) 'parse page
        Loop
        Loclist = strategy.GetResultantLocations
        If Loclist.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each Location In Loclist
            L = Location.GetRectangle.GetLeft
            B = Location.GetRectangle.GetBottom
            W = Location.GetRectangle.GetWidth
            H = Location.GetRectangle.GetHeight
            TextString = Location.GetText
            pg = Location.GetPageNumber
            CoordFile.WriteLine(TextString & Chr(9) & L & Chr(9) & B & Chr(9) & W & Chr(9) & H & Chr(9) & pg & Chr(9) & InputFileName)
        Next Location
        'Finished processing
        pdfDoc.Close() 'close pdf
        CoordFile.Close() 'close output file
    End Sub
```

I am getting the rectangle coordinates OK, and the matched text string, but location.GetPageNumber is always 0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Sorry to repeat the question but `TextString`, from `Location.GetText`, is getting the correct values, and Location.PageNumber is 0 always?

Comment: Yes. Location.GetRectangle and Location.GetText are getting the correct values, and Location.GetPageNumber is always 0.

I circumvented the problem meanwhile by putting the entire For Each Location loop inside the Do While (i.e. processing each page separately) I can then supply the pagenumber myself, but this is inelegant

Comment: I was looking at the documentation and it should be keeping that value for each rectangle.  Please post the new code, as a solution, as it may be the only workaround for the time-being.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround I used.
I re-initiate the strategy object and the parser object every page, and also output the locations matched by the Regex pattern per page.
That way I can use the pg counter of my own While loop instead of the one [not] given by the .PageNumber method:

```
    Private Sub Main() 'the main processing routine
        'Sub assumes that the PDF document (pdfDoc) and the output file (CoordFile) --both module level object-- are open and available
        Dim Location As iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.IPdfTextLocation
        Dim TextString As String
        Dim L, B, W, H As Single ' Left, bottom, width & height of the rectangle containing the extracted text
        Dim pg As Integer = 0 'number of current page, number of matches
        Dim N As Integer = 0
        Do While pg < pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages 'loop thru document pages 
            pg += 1
            Dim strategy As New iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(RegexPattern) 'extraction strategy (RegexPattern is a module variable)
            Dim Parser As iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor = New Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy)
            Parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetPage(pg)) 'parse page
            If strategy.GetResultantLocations.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Location In strategy.GetResultantLocations
                    TextString = Location.GetText
                    L = Location.GetRectangle.GetLeft
                    B = Location.GetRectangle.GetBottom
                    W = Location.GetRectangle.GetWidth
                    H = Location.GetRectangle.GetHeight
                    CoordFile.WriteLine(TextString & Chr(9) & L & Chr(9) & B & Chr(9) & W & Chr(9) & H & Chr(9) & pg)
                    N += 1
                Next Location
            End If
            strategy.GetResultantLocations.Clear() 'dispose loclist
        Loop

        'Finished processing
        pdfDoc.Close()
        CoordFile.Close() 'close output file
    End Sub
```

... not elegant but it works...

Comment: *"Here is a workaround I used. I re-initiate the strategy object and the parser object every page"* - Actually this is not a *workaround* but the *standard usage pattern*. The strategies don't know that a new page starts, they are just forwarded instructions for drawing content on a canvas. Thus, you *always* have to re-instantiate the strategy for each page unless it has some reset method you can use instead or it does not collect page-dependent data at all.